# Excel auto-fill any row with formula and prevent it from being deleted - programming only way?

Tags: vba, excel

Having an Excel problem, I searched the net. Found old answer on stack overflow, but it was both incomplete and also off topic of this forum.

Since incomplete I need a much better solution and fear it will require some (VBA-) programming. Thus I hope it is on topic.

My problem is this:
I have two sheets, one for input of data, and one for presenting/printing them. Because data is never "consistent", I had to make a trick and have a cell in each data-input-row be filled with consistent data for me to do vlookup sucessfull in the printing/presenting sheet.
And yes, autofilling the whole column (row 1 to 653..) initally does the trick.
But when users 1) delete old entries, at best they mark the rows and right click to delete not only data but the entire row, meaning that the number of rows with the actual formula decreases, or at worst just delete data in the row leaving a row without formulas in the cols I need to have rows in.
2) add new entries, they either insert a new row (thus not containing the formulas), by accident delete the formula(s) in the cells (haven't figured out yet how they manage, since the cols with formulas is hidden)

So, is there any way I can ensure that whatever the user does, there will always be formulas in any row in my hidden cols?

Respectfully I am not at all into VB/VBA, so if that is a solution (programming the col to contain the formula no matter what), please bear with me and provide the rookie-understandable answer for me to implement.

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Best regards,
Steen

Additional info:
Sorry if I'm being a real newbie, but if only I could upload a picture or an example file.

My sheet have headings: A is volunteer#, B is date, C is task (gardening, car wash, babysitting, baking, ....), D is hours worked on task, E is points per hour (using Vlookup to find points per hour for each task), and finally F (my problem) containing a formula (points per hour * hours worked).

Since everyone can (and should be able to) input a record ("I am volunteer no 1, and on the 12. of february I did gardening for 3 hours". The formula in F should result in 3 hours * 15 points).

My real formula is a bit more complicated than the example, but .... A formula is a formula.

So, when people fill in new entries or delete previous week-entries etc, it is quite random if they do it in a way that wil have the function in col F work.

If they insert a new row, me having filled entire col F with the function won't work, so they should go to next blank row (perhaps way down) to insert data.

If they delete marking the rows and right click+delete, they minimize number of rows with formula in it. If they mark rows and click delete, we get blank rows without data, formulas, whatever.

So how do I ensure that each cell in col F always will contain my formula no matter what?

Saw someone pointing to something called arrayformula, but couldn't see how I could implement it to work for me (poor examples, sadly).

Comment: For example, you can get rid of formulas, and add a command button. User can add or remove data, but when the button is pressed, button-related code can write the consisten data you mentioned. For a start, add a button, start macro recorder, and write a formula. The look at the generated code.

Comment: Can't you just protect the sheet or the columns so that they cannot be deleted?

Comment: Are you using structured tables? These can help somewhat with this kind of issue. Another piece is to use conditional formatting to show problems. I'm not real clear on your issues, but this post of mine might be helpful: http://yoursumbuddy.com/user-friendly-survey-without-vba/ There is also a request on Excel User Voice to be able to protect parts of tables and still allow deleting of rows, but that doesn't help you yet: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/16452913-get-tables-working-on-protected-sheets-add-rows